# Align elements in a fieldset using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, fieldset

I have a `form` with two `fieldsets` using `flexbox` to align elements. The second fieldset contains two buttons which I want display in a row and centered in this row.

```
/-----------------------------------\
|     /----------\ /----------\     |
|<-x->| Button A | | Button B |<-x->|
|     \----------/ \----------/     |
\-----------------------------------/
```

I have prepared this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9k5y/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are not all flexbox elements behaving like flexbox divs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679337/why-are-not-all-flexbox-elements-behaving-like-flexbox-divs)

Comment: [Flexbox not working on button or fieldset elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35464067/3597276)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexbox and `<fieldset>` don't mix well: http://jsfiddle.net/w9k5y/9/ So you better wrap flex-box instructions with a `<div>` for now.

But for this case you don't even have to use flexbox. `text-align: center;` brings you the same result: http://jsfiddle.net/w9k5y/1/ It's the same idea as Romain had, but you don't necessarily need the extra `<div>` this time.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to create a div container around your buttons. 
Set up a variable/fixed width of the container equal at your buttons total width.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/w9k5y/4/)

**HTML**

```
 <div id="container">
    <button>Button A</button>
    <button>Button B</button>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
   width: 30%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Otherwise, there is a wild way to do it.

[You can review it here](http://jsfiddle.net/w9k5y/5/)

**CSS**

```
#container {
 text-align: center 
}
```