# Why are not all flexbox elements behaving like flexbox divs?

Tags: css, flexbox, fieldset

Why is flexbox not working properly with `fieldset` or other non-`div` tags?
I expect them to line up next to each other like in the `div` example, as `flex-direction: row;` is default in flexbox. However `fieldset` is force applying a width to them, and I do not understand why.

HTML

```
<fieldset>
    <div>fieldset flexbox</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
</fieldset>

<div id="parentdiv">
    <div>div flexbox<div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

CSS: All elements are set to `display: flex`;

http://jsfiddle.net/c5BB5/1/

Comment: Define 'not working properly' - What are you expecting?

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Struggled to phrase the questions. Updated it now. Understandable?

Comment: If this is an extension of your original question, update the original rather than reposting:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678166/is-it-possible-to-make-all-elements-on-the-page-a-display-flex-flexbox

Comment: @cimmanon: Nope, they are different. This questions is related to the fact that non-div tags like fieldset do not get the expected flexbox properties when they are set. The other questions is a css-selector questions of how to give all elements on a page the same display:flex-property. They might seem to be the same at first sight, but they really are not:)

Comment: [Flexbox not working on button or fieldset elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35464067/3597276)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is down to browser bugs to do with the `fieldset` element.

It's [a known issue with `fieldset` elements in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=262679). [Firefox has a similar (very old) issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=292736) in that `legend` and `fieldset` are [replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element).

---

I guess it's safer to use a `<div role="group">` instead of a real fieldset for now. In your CSS you could use `div[role='group']` as your selector. See http://www.deque.com/aria-group-viable-alternative-fieldset-legend for more information.

Comment: Thanks @ollyhodgson for pointing this out. Never thought it would be a browser bug. Try the jsfiddle in Opera, Opera Next, Firefox, Safari and Chrome. I guess this is the correct result I should expect: http://d.pr/i/iKzw ? (I only get that in Opera 12.15 Mac.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd expect to happen. I guess it's safer to use a `<div role="group">` instead of a real `fieldset` for now. In your CSS you could use `div[role='group']` as your selector. See http://www.deque.com/aria-group-viable-alternative-fieldset-legend

Comment: A year and a half this bug remains intact in both browsers... :(

Comment: @Pere Indeed - the Firefox bug was raised in 2005! Use `<div role="group">` instead of `<fieldset>` if you need complex styling.

Comment: Yeah @OllyHodgson, I already did that, but thanks again for pointing out!